# Problems with Qtile due to GNOME

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I recently installed qtile according to the docs and when running `qtile start` I got the following message:

```
not starting; existing window manager GNOME Shell
```

Now, I digged a bit more and found [this](https://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/config/gnome.html), which, after doing everything it said, still isn't working. I am at a loss on what is required to make it work... Maybe I should ditch GNOME somehow? Any input is welcome, thanks.

#### Edits

Ubuntu version: 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Start with what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: We, of course, cannot be sure if you did everything said over there correctly.

Comment: If you aren't going to help, why comment at all? And anyway if I knew what I did incorrectly I wouldn't ask here, that's the whole point.

Comment: Same stumbling block; what is the relationship between gnome and qtile?  Clearly you can run qtile inside gnome, so... qtile can run without gnome? Is gnome a competitor and qtile can replace it completely?